# Drive stopped working on windows server 2003 and I receive a "controller error"

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, controller, drive-failure

I have a Proliant 360 Hp server with Windows server 2003 R2.  I can only access the server in safe mode.

The event viewer is completely filled up with this error:

```
The driver detected a controller error on Device\Harddisk3\DR3
```

I figured out which drive was affected. It is drive `H` that is a secondary non mirrored drive.

When I access anything on that drive I receive:

```
The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error
```

What should I do?  Is this just a driver issue or a hard drive failure?

Comment: I executed chkdsk H: /f and I was surprised to see this tool perform many fixes. Unfortunately I lost the output it produced :(. It fixed certain indexes, and many "orphaned files". After this the drive was accessible again. Now I am trying a restart in normal mode and I will update on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 days of running smoothly I can confirm that the issue was completely fixed by using chkdsk /f on the drive.

The troubleshooting guide didn't contain this, which instead is one of the first thing that should be done.

Now I added chkdsk to my maintanance plan of the server automatically running this command every few months on all drives:

```
@echo off
(echo n
echo y)|chkdsk {drive letter}: /f
```

(It would execute the chkdsk on a restart without forcing one)

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, the event id 11 message is being posted due to hardware problems with either the controller or, more likely, a device that is attached to the controller in question. The hardware problems can be associated with poor cabling, incorrect termination or transfer rate settings, lazy or slow device responses to relinquish the SCSI bus, a faulty device, or, in very rare cases, a poorly written device driver.

[The troubleshooting guide for windows server.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154690/en-us)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However in this case the issue was completely fixed by using chkdsk /f.

Comment: I think that's in that guide somewhere too :p